# Add custom fields to JSON file based on user input from YAML file - Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, yaml

I am new to Python. I am having the one YAML file and I am accessing it with a Python file. In YAML file, there is fields option. In YAML file, User can set variables with values. The Python file reads the variables with values and then adds it to the JSON file. Note that the variables and values can be changed according to user.
How can I make this possible?

Here is the sample code:

```
import yaml
from datetime import datetime
import os
import json

#name for json file
name = "stack.json"

#load data from yml file
data = yaml.safe_load(open('stack.yml'))
data2 = data.get('heartbeat.monitors')

#Current time stamp
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")

#ip
ip ='192.168.1.1'

#getting data from the field and assign it to variable
for item in data2:
    if item["type"] == "icmp":
        fields_under_root = (item["fields_under_root"])

        # if fields_under_root is true,code goes here
        if fields_under_root == True:
            fields = (item["fields"])
            print(fields)
            locals().update(fields)
        #code to be entered

        #if fields_under_root is false, code goes here
        elif fields_under_root == False:
            fields = (item["fields"])
            print(fields)
        #code to be entered
#For writing in JSON File
#Creates a JSON file if not exists
if not os.path.exists(name):
    with open(name, 'w') as f:
        f.write('{}')

#list for storing the values
result = [(timestamp, {'monitor.ip': ip,"fields": fields })]

#For writing in JSON File
with open(name, 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    f.truncate()
    for entry in result:
        _entry = '"{}":{},\n'.format(entry[0], json.dumps(entry[1]))
        _entry = _entry.encode()
        f.write(_entry)
    f.write('}'.encode('ascii'))
```

In YAML file:

```
heartbeat.monitors:
- type: icmp
  fields:
    a: steven
    b: kumar

  fields_under_root: True
```

My output in JSON file:

```
{"February 18 2019, 17:04:30":{"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.1", "fields": {"b": "kumar", "a": "steven"}},
}
```

Required output if `fields_under_root` is `True`:

```
{"February 18 2019, 17:04:30":{"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.1", "b": "kumar", "a": "steven"},
}
```

Required output if `fields_under_root` is `False`:

```
{"February 18 2019, 17:04:30":{"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.1", "fields.b": "kumar", "fields.a": "steven"},
}
```

Comment: why do the conditional checks in your code do the same thing? also why are you updating `locals`

Comment: I didn't add the code on conditional fields. Tell me some suggestion to make the output.

Comment: Next time, just edit your question instead of [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746721/add-custom-fields-based-on-user-input-to-json/54746977#54746977) it, and copy-and-pasting the contents into a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an input file:

```
...

heartbeat.monitors:
- type: icmp
  fields:
    a: steven
    b: kumar
  # If this option is set to true, the custom fields are stored as top-level
  # fields in the output document instead of being grouped under a fields
  # sub-dictionary. Default is false.
  fields_under_root: True
```

your program should have a function that does all the work, then it is easy to test
both versions of the input, by updating the input file.:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from datetime import datetime
import os
import json

# name for json file
json_name = 'stack.json'
yaml_name = 'stack.yaml'


# Current time stamp
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S')


def gen_output(data, json_filename):
    ip = '192.168.1.1'
    val = {'monitor.ip': ip}
    result = dict(timestamp=val)

    # getting data from the field and assign it to variable

    for item in data:
        if item['type'] == 'icmp':
            fields = item.pop('fields')
            if item['fields_under_root']:
                val.update(fields)
            else:
                nf = {}
                for k in fields:
                    nf['fields.' + k] = fields[k]
                val.update(nf)

    with open(json_filename, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(result, fp, ensure_ascii=False)


# load data from YAML file
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
with open('stack.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
data2 = data.get('heartbeat.monitors')

gen_output(data2, json_name)

# show the output file
with open('stack.json') as fp:
    print(fp.read())

print('---------')
# update the YAML input file
with open('stack.yaml') as fp:
    yamlrt = ruamel.yaml.YAML() # default is round-trip, preserving comments
    data = yaml.load(fp)
data['heartbeat.monitors'][0]['fields_under_root'] = False
with open(yaml_name, 'wb') as fp:
    yamlrt.dump(data, fp)

with open('stack.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
data2 = data.get('heartbeat.monitors')

gen_output(data2, json_name)
with open('stack.json') as fp:
    print(fp.read())
```

which gives:

```
{"timestamp": {"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.1", "a": "steven", "b": "kumar"}}
---------
{"timestamp": {"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.1", "fields.a": "steven", "fields.b": "kumar"}}
```

Generic comments:

- don't test for `== False` or `== True`, if at all test with `is
  False` or `is True`, but better just test a variable `x` that
  contains a boolean with `if x:` and don't do both, a boolean, if not
  `True` is `False`, hence use a plain `else:`
- don't hassle with outputting JSON. No need to truncate, seek
  etc. Just make sure your data is correctly formed and then dump in one go. That 
  makes sure your output is valid JSON.
- don't add comments stating the obvious  `#ip`
- add a space after the comment token `#`, many lint-ers complain about not having that
- I use ruamel.yaml in the above (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), because with
  PyYAML programmaticly updating your YAML file would lose you the comment information.
  And because `YAML(typ='safe').load()` is faster than PyYAML's `yaml.load()`
  (Apart from that PyYAML *only* supports the outdated YAML 1.1)

Comment: Thanks for the Code. It worked. Thanks for the Comments. I will keep in mind and rectify my mistakes in future.